# Extend vline slightly beyond surrounding box?

Tags: lists, enumerate, rules, line, vertical

Is there a way to extend a `\vline` slightly beyond the boundary of the surrounding box? In the case I have in mind, I'm attempting to have a continuous vertical line between several items in an `enumerate` environment. This is what I've got going so far:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[] \parbox{0.47\linewidth}{\textbf{Version 1}}
            \hfill\vline\hfill
            \parbox{0.47\linewidth}{\textbf{Version 2}}
    \item   \parbox[t]{0.47\linewidth}{Text that may cross to \\ a second line}
            \hfill\vline\hfill
            \parbox[t]{0.47\linewidth}{Text that may cross to \\ a second line}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

This works well for lining up the vertical lines, but naturally there's a small gap between each line. I know I could use `\rule`, but then I'd have to manually set the height for every single item since they sometimes cover more than one line.

I'm open to other general solutions for the vertical line, but I'd like to use `enumerate` still because items will sometimes be cross-referenced elsewhere in the text and I'd like those to work as hyperlinks. For example, I know this would be easy to do using `tabular`, but then I'd either lose cross-referencing or have to jump through some hoops to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** after comment.

This example uses `tikz` and the `tikzmark` library to draw a continuous vertical line.

*(You don't need to understand tikz code)*

The command

`\DrawVerticalRule[<color of the line>]{<name of the top mark>}{<name of the bottom mark>}`

(color is optional, default = black) will draw the vertical line between two tikzmarks.

Before using `\DrawVerticalRule`, you must manually
add the two `\tikzmark{<unique name>}`, before the beginning of each sentence. In the case of the bottom mark, it must be inserted after the last `\\`,  with no white-space before the first word of the line.

Notice that `\hfill` was added between the parboxes to add some space between them, and prevent the vertical line from touching the end of a long sentence.

The line will have an x-offset of `1ex` to the left and will extend above or below each first letter by 1pt. The chosen line width is 0.8pt.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%********************************** added  <<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\newlength{\xshift} 
\setlength{\xshift}{1ex} % line separation from the text <<<<
\newlength{\yshift} 
\settoheight{\yshift}{M} % height of M
\newlength{\zshift} 
\settodepth{\zshift}{gjpqy} % depth of g    

\newcommand{\DrawVerticalRule}[3][black]{% \DrawVerticalRule[<color of the line>] default = black
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [color=#1, line width=0.8pt]($ (pic cs:#2) +(-\xshift,\yshift+1pt) $) -- ($ (pic cs:#3) +(-\xshift,-\zshift-1pt) $); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%*************************************

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[] \parbox{0.47\linewidth}{\textbf{Version 3}}\hfill % space between the parboxes
    \parbox{0.47\linewidth}{\textbf{\tikzmark{t1}Version 4}} % add the first tikzmark <<<<<<<<<
        \item   \parbox[t]{0.47\linewidth}{Text that may cross to \\ a second line and it is longer...}\hfill % space between the parboxes
        \parbox[t]{0.47\linewidth}{Text that may cross to\\ \tikzmark{b1}a second line}% add the second tikzmark <<<<<<<<
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
    
\DrawVerticalRule[blue]{t1}{b1} % draw the vertical line between the two tikzmarks t1 and b1 <<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[] \parbox{0.47\linewidth}{\textbf{Version 5}}\hfill % space between the parboxes
        \parbox{0.47\linewidth}{\textbf{\tikzmark{t2}Version 6}} % add the first tikzmark <<<<<<<<<
        \item   \parbox[t]{0.47\linewidth}{Text that may cross to \\ a second line and it is longer...}\hfill % space between the parboxes
        \parbox[t]{0.47\linewidth}{Text that may cross to\\a second line and maybe use \\  \tikzmark{b2}a third line.}% add the second tikzmark <<<<<<<<
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\DrawVerticalRule[red]{t2}{b2} % draw the vertical line between the two tikzmarks t2 and b2<<<<<<<<<<


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works almost perfect! 2 probs: if a line of text in the left col reaches the end of the box, the line goes through the last char, and if text wraps on the right col of the last item, it requires some trial and error to place \tikzmark{lower} correctly.

Comment: @joshisanonymous Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer. The marks are inserted manually, the lower after the the last "\\" and before the first word for that line.